# How to fetch seekbar float value in android

Tags: android, android-seekbar

*hi am trying to fetch the seekarbar value with the help og `getProgress` Method.Am able to fetch the value in `integer` ,but i need to fetch the `float` value of the `seekbar`*.

```
  double goal=bar.getProgress();
```

*I have used above method to retrieve the value but its giving  `integer` value instead of `float` value.*
Plz help  .Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SeekBar with decimal values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197674/seekbar-with-decimal-values)

Comment: @NJNileshJ I want to use the progress value to compare with some other value where m using the 'getprogess()'method.The link you have shared is setting the progress value.

Answer (score 1):

This is the working code for get seekbar current values you have to try  this.  it works fine.If you want to get seekbar values in float then use float instead of int .

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{

SeekBar mSeekBar;
TextView mProgressText;
TextView mTrackingText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      mSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seek);
        mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        mProgressText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.progress);
        mTrackingText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tracking);
    }

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {
        mProgressText.setText(progress + " " +
                getString(R.string.seekbar_from_touch) + "=" + fromTouch);
    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        mTrackingText.setText(getString(R.string.seekbar_tracking_on));
    }

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        mTrackingText.setText(getString(R.string.seekbar_tracking_off));
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is for setting the value of the seekbar but what am asking is how to retrieve the seekbar value.

Comment: Scroll the seek bar it will dynamically change the seekbar  values, i am getting the seekbar values on progresschange and that value is set in the text

Comment: My scenario is i have to fetch the value of the seekbar and compare with other variable to get things done.The Text View is working fine for me also but at the same time retrieval of seekbar value is integer not float value.In the text view of the seekbar the float value is showing but while retrieving its taking the integer value.

Comment: use Math.round(f) to round the float value and compare that value

Comment: thankyou i just divided  the value of the seekbar by 10 now,its working fine ;

Comment: Happy to  help you... :)